# Stochastic order of Max

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider an array $\{\{X_{ni}\}_{i=1}^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ s.t. for each $i$, $X_{ni}=o_p(n^\alpha)$. What is the order of $M_n=\max_{1\le i\le n}X_{ni}$?

I got the following

$$P\{|M_n|>n^\alpha\epsilon\}\le \sum_{i=1}^n P\{|X_{ni}|>n^\alpha\epsilon\}$$

So, if $P\{|X_{ni}|>n^\alpha\epsilon\}\in o(n^{-(1+\delta)})$ for some $\delta>0$ then $M_n=o_p(n^\alpha)$ as well.

However, can we say anything else? Thank's!